# VS project referenced from two excluded libraries

Tags: c#, reference

I have two versions of my application. The first one use references of library LIB_A, the second one use references of library LIB_B. (LIB_A and LIB_B are in fact to versions of the same product, but they differ from each other, even namespaces are different.There can't be installed two versions in the one machine on the same time). 
Sourcecodes of my application in both versions are almost the same so I need to have one solution, that can switch which library to use.
How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you specified VS2010 in your comment, I'm adding this answer separately, so that users of VS2015 can refer to the other answer, which is a lot cleaner.

In VS2010, you can use source code sharing between the two projects. Let's say that you have created AppA, which is the app project that references LibA, and contains all the sources for the app.

You can create an app project, AppB, that references LibB. It also *shares* all the sources of AppA. This can be done in one of two ways:

**Linking All Sources Manually**

In AppB, you can create the same folder structure (if any) as AppA. Right click each subfolder and click Add->Existing Item... Navigate to the corresponding folder of AppA and select all the C# files. Now click on the *dropdown* to the right of the Add button and select "Add as Link". You'll notice that the added sources have a little "shared" arrow in their icons, and that their paths point back to the original.

**Linking All Sources Dynamically**

If you have lots of files in AppA, or add/remove files regularly, the previous approach can get tiring. There's another way to do this that involves hand-editing AppB.csproj. Open AppB.csproj and create an `ItemGroup` that imports all the files from AppA. This code assumes that AppA and AppB are subfolders of the solution folder. If not, change the relative paths appropriately.

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="..\AppA\\**\*.cs">
      <Link>%(RecursiveDir)%(FileName)%(Extension)</Link>
    </Compile>
  </ItemGroup>
```

Now when you open the solution, you will see that AppB's contents match that of AppA. The sources are linked, so AppB's conditional build settings (if any) will apply.

You can also exclude files from being included by adding an `Exclude` attribute to the `Compile` tag. See the VS documentation for more details.

The only downside of this approach is that you need to hand-edit the csproj file. Also, if you accidentally delete or move linked files, VS will hard-code the list of linked files into the project. The files themselves will still be linked.

Comment: Ok, thanks, that solves some problems. But how can I force shared sources to switch references. For example: Now I have two simmilar common.cs files. The first one use reference to LibA, the second use reference to LibB. Is there a possibility to do something like #if LIB_A using LIBA #endif if LIB_B using LIB_B #endif ?

Comment: Conditional compilation begins with the project itself. For example, double click on AppA\Properties in the solution explorer, and go to the Build tab. Then enter LIB_A in the conditional compilation symbols field (you can enter multiple symbols separated by semicolons.) Then your shared sources can use #if LIB_A /#elif / #endif statements like the ones you wrote.

Comment: By the way, since you're new to stackoverflow, do vote and/or accept answers that you find useful.

Comment: Thanks,  conditional compilation symbols is exactly what I was looking for! BTW:I was trying to vote but I have too low reputation points:(

Comment: Glad to help. If this answer solved your problem, you can mark it accepted by clicking on the tick icon to the left.

Answer (score 0):

It so happens that Visual Studio 2015 (you can download the Release Candidate, which I've found much more powerful and faster than VS2013) has a feature that is designed for this very purpose - [Shared Projects](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/7ca517/shared-project-an-impressive-features-of-visual-studio-201/). Here's a [Channel9 video](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Visual-Studio/Connect-event-2014/517) that describes it.

A shared project contains source files that are compiled directly into projects that reference it. Let's say a shared project Shared has a file foo.cs, and projects AppA and AppB both reference project Shared, then file foo.cs is compiled directly into AppA and AppB - it uses any conditional settings of those projects. So foo.cs could have code that looks like this

```
#if APPA
// do something
#elif APPB
// do something else
#endif
```

So to summarize:

1. Within a single solution, create a Shared Project with all your app sources.
2. Create two projects AppA and AppB, that represent the two flavors of your app.
3. AppA references Shared and Lib_A. AppB references Shared and Lib_B.
4. If needed, add compile variables that control differences in the sources as described above.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunatelly I'm obligated to do it in VS 2010.